# Getting null value for request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") while retrieving client IP address in java?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, networking, ip

I have deployed my web application on Tomcat 6.0 in machine having ip address 10.xx.xx.90. Then i am making a http request(from browser) to this app from m/c having ip address (10.xx.xx.56).

I am trying to get the IP address of client(10.xx.xx.56) in my app using the below code. But I am getting null value for request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") where as request.getRemoteAddr() returns the ip address of the machine on which the application is deployed i.e 10.xx.xx.90.

But, if I make a http call to the application from standalone java program I am able to get the client m/c ip address. So, what is the correct way to get the client IP address. Do I need to configure something in my tomcat ??

```
   String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
       if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }
```

Comment: How do you know `ipAddress` is null after `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")`? Are you logged or just guess? `request.getRemoteAddr()` will return client's IP while `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` will return all IPs (including proxy). So you might getting the value from `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")`

Comment: @pmp I am logging both the ip address values and getting null value in log for request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"). Also getting null values in local while debugging.

Comment: is there any proxy server or load balancer before the TOMCAT?

Comment: @kasharma: There is no loadbalancer here but i don't know about the proxy server. How to check if there is any proxy server ?

Comment: Let say tomact server ip is (X.Y.Z) and proxy server ip is (P.Q.R)if from browser you are directly making http://X.Y.Z/your_app/,that means there is no proxy in between. How ever you if you are not making a direct hit to the server and it is routing through like below     http://P.Q.R/proxy --> http://X.Y.Z/your_app/ ,this is how proxy works, I asked this question to you,because the proxy server might modify the x-forwarded-for header.

Comment: @kasharma : There is no proxy in between. I am directly accessing the app by url X.Y.Z/my_app/..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) you should know it. However, the end-client could presumably be behind a regular web-proxy. Anyway, the load balancer or proxy would set "X-Forwarded-For". From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) article,

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header field is a de facto standard for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer.

Based on your comments and question there isn't a proxy or load balancer. For best practices I would recommend you check that header first. If it's null then use `request.getRemoteAddr()` (which you reported as working).